# Magento 2 multiple countries setup multi store or multi website?

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, multi-website, multicurrency, geoip

I want to setup magento 2 instance with below requirements in Magento 2.3 CE

1) **Multiple countries** option with country switcher

- UAE/Dubai (default)
- KSA/Saudi Arabia (This will further have below regions)

  - KSA Dammam
  - KSA Jeddah
  - KSA Riyadh
- Kuwait

2) **Multiple languages** with language switcher

- English (default)
- Arabic

3) **Multiple currency**

- AED (default)
- SAR
- KWD

4) **Catalog different** for each country, but there may be **few common products**

5) **Catalog data** will be uploaded for **each language**

6) **Inventory will not be shared** among countries

7) **Customers will be shared** across countries

8) **URL** should be as below

https://www.domain.com/uae/

https://www.domain.com/saudi/

9) If customers are shared, how will the cart and order process behave if the catalog is different in different countries

10) Auto redirection to country website with **GeoIP redirection**

With a bit of research I found that we can create multi website with same domain by creating a subfolder under root directory. Below are some of the links:

[Magento 2: How to configure Nginx to use multiple websites with sub-folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195175/magento-2-how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-multiple-websites-with-sub-folder)
- It is giving 404 error for category, product pages

https://gist.github.com/thagxt/0f605f0a8a95c79302db0d2f04383788

But I doubt if all the above requirements can be achieved?

Can this be achieved with multi-website OR multi-store configurations?

Kindly suggest the best approach possible and if above can be achieved with some 3rd party modules.

Answer (score 1):

All the above requirements are achievable. I have created a website based on these requirements. The tough part is the Regions on Saudi Store. You need to have multi-website configuration.No modules 3rd Party Modules are required.
Pingback if you want a detailed explanation. I will be glad to help you with this requirement.

Comment: Hi @prakash-tripathi, how did you achieve the above please?