# Magento 2.3 - LEMP Localhost - For Multi Website where should be create Symbolic links folder - Root folder or Pub folder?

Tags: magento2.3.3, nginx, multi-website, linux

I just want to create multi-website, i read some links to guide me to create a subfolder and create symbolic links of app,pub,lib,var and copy index.php & .htaccess from root folder to a subfolder.

Here where i can create a subfolder  **Root folder** or **Pub folder**?

This guide leads to create under **Root** folder => https://meetanshi.com/blog/setup-magento-2-multi-store/

This guide leads to create under **Pub** folder => https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198257/57334

**Which one should I follow?**

And how to add my localhost URL to my Nginx configuration, most of the documents and online links teach only live URL.

My single store Nginx Configuration :

```
server {
listen 8087;
server_name gomart;
set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/gomart;
include /usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/nginx.conf.sample;
error_log /usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/gomart_error.log;
access_log /usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/gomart_access.log;
set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
}

upstream fastcgi_backend2 {
server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Meetanshi's link as it is tried, tested, and approved in local as well as three live websites too.

Thank you.

Comment: After completed all the steps, how to configure Nginx? My current Nginx => https://justpaste.it/7bkdv How to configure multi-website? My seconf store url : http: //192.168.1.64:8080/grocery

Comment: Root folder path : usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/    :: Subfolder path : usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/grocery  > Index. php => https://justpaste.it/9q5m7 & .htaccess => https://justpaste.it/2vprh & symbolic links of app, pub, lib, var

Comment: MULTI WEBSITE URL => 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery  404 error screenshot => https://snipboard.io/kydph2.jpg

Comment: Any help for setup LEMP localost Multi Website url to nginx configuration? Nginx : justpaste.it/8d5xm Main website : Path - usr/share/nginx/html/gomart, URL - 192.168.1.65:8087/ Multi-website : URL - 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery/