# Magento 2 - Multi Website on same domain with subdirectory

Tags: magento2, nginx, server-setup, multi-website

We have an nginx, varnish setup of a Magento 2.2.2. installation in production.

There are several websites which can be accessed via store view code. This looks like this:
domain.com/us/
domain.com/de/
domain.com/jp/
(show store view code is enabled)

Now we also want to add different languages so this means we need to add another subdirectory to the path.

This is what we want to achieve:
domain.com/us/en/
domain.com/us/es/
domain.com/de/de/
domain.com/jp/jp/
(these are examples, first subdirectory is website, second store view)

So I tried to change the base url and base url link to domain.com/us/
This works for the home page but all deeper links end in an redirect loop.

No nginx changes done so far. Was hoping it works simply with changing base urls.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: please use search. you need to either use proper rewrite, or use magento extension to control language... probably with geoip

Comment: Okay finally found a working solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195175/magento-2-how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-multiple-websites-with-sub-folder

Comment: I also have implimented this with following way
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193679/magento-2-how-to-set-multi-websites-on-the-same-url/351729#351729