# Issue in setting multi website with two servers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, nginx, multi-website

I'm trying to setup Multi website in AWS server. I found several solution for Multi website implementation.

In my case, There are two different servers(`assume 0.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.2`) where magento has installed on both the servers. I need to **unlink the server configuration for 0.0.0.1** Magento and **make 0.0.0.2 as default website** and **configure 0.0.0.1 as multi website in 0.0.0.2**. I have done the multi website, store and storeview configuration in 0.0.0.2.

How do I update the server configuration for 0.0.0.1? Should I update its virtual host or /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento or any other files to point to 0.0.0.2.

If this is resolved then I should be able to proceed with next steps in order to complete the multi website implementation.

We use nginx as web server. Using AWS server for development purpose.

Comment: I created multi website for AWS public ec2 domain and for its IP address. You can refer here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193679/magento-2-how-to-set-multi-websites-on-the-same-url/358597#358597

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace this code to magento index.php

```
 <?php

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$params = $_SERVER;
    
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code'; //Webite code as same in admin panel
    
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    
 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    
 /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

 $bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Want to know that how the main server receive the request from 0.0.0.1. And the solution which you provided to be added in 0.0.0.2 Magento right?

Comment: are you using single magento for multiple websites right ?

Comment: Yes like I said, each ip has installed with Magento. I want to use 2nd server as Main website and 1st ip for multi website. Also, want to know that how do I unlink Magento  from 1st server and point to 2nd server. And use them(IP) for multi website.